# All functions such that $f'(x) = f(x+1)-f(x) = \frac{f(x+2)-f(x)}{2}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

I would like to find all (differentiable) functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $$f'(x) = f(x+1)-f(x) = \frac{f(x+2)-f(x)}{2}$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I claim that the only functions are $f(x) = ax+b$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. My proof goes as the following:

Since $f'(x) = f(x+1)-f(x)$ and $f$ is differentiable, $f'$ is differentiable and we have $f''(x) = f'(x+1)-f'(x)$. By assumptions we get $2f'(x)+f(x) = f(x+2)$ and thus $$f'(x+1) = f(x+1+1)-f(x+1) = f(x+2)-f(x+1) = 2f'(x)+f(x)-f(x+1) = 2f'(x)-f'(x) = f'(x)$$ Therefore $f'(x+1)=f'(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $f''(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This proves that $f(x) = ax+b$.

Is this proof correct? If not, what is wrong with it and what other functions satisfy these conditions?

Comment: It looks perfectly legitimate to me!

Comment: It seems to me that half of the proof is missing: how do you conclude that $f(x) = ax+b$ from $f'(x) = f'(x+1)$ and $f''(x) = 0$?

Comment: @AlexM.: Isn't that just by integrating twice? We have $f'(x)=\int 0\ dx=b$ and $f(x)=\int b\ dx=ax+b$.

Comment: From $f''(x) = 0$ it follows that $f'(x) = c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. All functions $f$ with $f'(x) = c$ are of the form $f(x) = cx+b$, for let $g$ be a function with $g'(x) = c$. Then $h(x):=g(x)-cx$ is differentiable and we have $h'(x) = c-c = 0$ and thus $h(x) = b$ for some $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and therefore $g(x) = h(x)+cx = b+cx$. QED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to phrase it is
$$
f(x+1)-f(x)=\frac{f(x+2)-f(x)}2\iff f(x+1)-f(x)=f(x+2)-f(x+1)
$$
and in the last equation the LHS equals $f'(x)$ and the RHS equals $f'(x+1)$. Thus
$$
f''(x)=f'(x+1)-f'(x)=0
$$
From this it follows that $f'(x)=\int 0\ dx=b$ and thus $f(x)=\int b\ dx=ax+b$.

Comment: You have made a small mistake: the problem says that ff is differentiable (and this usually means differentiable once), yet you use the second derivative. You should reformulate your solution in such a way as to avoid this.

Comment: @AlexM: Since $f'(x)$ can be written in terms of $f(x)$ it is differentiable too. By induction this actually implies $f$ to be smooth, but that is not needed.